# DevArt Oracle EF Core - Case insensitive string compare + NULLS

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, devart

I can't seem to find any sensible/reliable way of performing case-insensitive string comparison when using DevArt EF Core with Oracle when NULLs are involved

Assume there's a table with column "Name" which is a nullable string (varchar(50)).

Firstly, none of these options affect the generated SQL at all;

```
OracleEntityProviderConfig.Instance.QueryOptions.CaseInsensitiveComparison = true;
OracleEntityProviderConfig.Instance.QueryOptions.CaseInsensitiveLike = true;
OracleEntityProviderConfig.Instance.QueryOptions.UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior = true;
```

**.ToLower();**

```
var result = repo.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToLower() == searchValue.ToLower());
```

This works, but if searchValue is null the x.Name.ToLower() causes a NREx so can't reliably use that (without putting loads of ugly null checks - and can't use ?. in LINQ statements)

**.Equals()**

```
result = repo.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(searchValue, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

This generates;

```
WHERE UPPER("Name") = UPPER('somevalue')
```

But if searchValue is null it never matches as the only valid way to compare for null is

```
WHERE "Name" is null
```

The EF Core DevArt Adapter doesn't change the **Name = 'value'** to **is null** as I think it should.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up writing ToLowerNullSafe() string extension method which (guards against nulls) is accepted by LINQ and converts to 'is null' correctly